# Are the brackets used to define an array in php not supported?

Tags: php

I tried to define an simple array in php, and I got an "unexpected '[' error message.

Code:

```
<?php
      $days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"];
      echo "Value at index 1 is ". $days[1];
?>
```

while using the `$days = array("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri");` works fine

Comment: That will depend on your PHP version.

Comment: I am using netbeans 8.1, is this no longer supported or newly supported ?@frz3993

Comment: Do you mean netbeans the IDE ?  The brackets is supported for PHP 5.4 and above.

Comment: @frz3993 yes, I changed the php version in ampps and it worked, I'm still new to php, but thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your version of PHP is < 5.4 you cannot use [] to define an array. Create a page that contains:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

and see what version that says. Alternatively, if you have shell access to the server you're working on, typ this on the command line:

```
`php -v`
```

Comment: I was running php 5.3, thank you :)